# php-cgi suddenly very slow with minimal CPU on DMZ server

Tags: php, iis, moodle, fastcgi, iis-8.5

We have a Moodle IIS implementation where the primary data/IIS server is on our LAN, but we also have a public facing IIS server on our DMZ. Until recently, performance when accessing Moodle via the DMZ server was on-par with accessing via the LAN server; but last week I noticed that accessing via the DMZ was very slow and I was often getting 500 timeouts. I increased Activity Timeout for fastcgi and the timeouts disappeared, but the site is now *painfully* slow.

I monitored Activity Monitor when browsing the site using the LAN server and php-cgi.exe  shows CPU goes up while actively browsing (20-25% or so). Monitoring the same on the DMZ server shows no change in CPU utilisation for the php-cgi processes - they all stay at 0-1%.

I moved the DMZ server to the LAN and the performance was immediately as expected: pages loaded quickly and php-cgi CPU utilisation goes up to 20-25% while browsing.

I tested pings and bandwidth when copying files between LAN and DMZ servers and the pings are around 20ms and the bandwidth seems capped at 100 Mbps when on the DMZ. That was unexpected, but I don't have historic pings to prove that latency used to be lower and bandwidth used to be higher.

Our core network provider recently performed maintenance and access to our DMZ dropped completely for a period until they 'fixed' the issue. It feels like they've introduced a bottleneck recently (traffic now routing through a 100 Mbps adapter?) and I have an open ticket, but I'm not sure how to prove this is the issue.

The only logs I can think to check are for IIS and looking at response-time. It looks like this has gone up 2-4x since the maintenance, but it's not as conclusive as I'd like (I'm guessing due to a good amount being locally cached). Is there anything else I could/should be looking at?

Servers are Windows Data Center 2012 R2, php is 7.4 nts 64-bit, and Moodle is 3.10.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description. When the server hangs, crashes or performance is low, it is usually necessary to grab the server's thread stack (Thread Dump) for subsequent analysis. So I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com, there will be professional technicians to assist you in grabbing the dump file and analyzing it.